# Почему сервер возвращает 401 ошибку при отправке запроса на django сервер с access токеном в заголовке на хостинге TimeWeb?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, jwt

Развернул сайт на django по инструкции. Все работает, за исключением JWT авторизации. При попытке авторизации с access-токеном сервер возвращает 401 ошибку с телом ответа: {detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."}. В запросе на закрытый API отправляется заголовок Authorization, как положено, причем запрос на refresh с refresh-токеном в теле выполняется успешно и возвращает access-токен. Пробовал отправлять запрос вручную из postman'а, результат одинаковый. Проводили тестирование на локальном хосте и на хостинге pythonanywhere - подобных проблем не возникло. Прикреплю файл с curl'ом запроса с access-токеном. Было бы здорово, если бы вы помогли с такой проблемой.

```
curl 'https://cc55796.tw1.ru/api/news/' \
-H 'authority: cc55796.tw1.ru' \
-H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
-H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
-H 'authorization: Bearer  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzA2MDM5OTc0LCJpYXQiOjE3MDYwMzk2MDksImp0aSI6ImQyMjE3MTE2ODU5OTQ1Mjc5M2Q3MWNlNDlkZjY4ZjU2IiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MX0.TjIJRdbPigQKhjCZr-7jC0aB8xkYuKOFdZrl9sCJO5E' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
```

Раскрыть

Есть еще информация. Я сделал тестовый роут и отправил туда запрос с заголовком Authorization. Обработчик роута возвращает заголовки запроса, поступившего на него. Оказалось, там нет заголовка Authorization в принципе, хотя я его отправляю. Прикреплю скриншот из postman.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На локальном сервере и на pythonanywhere хостинге все работает отлично, все запросы возвращаются с 200 кодом. На timeweb хостинге именно с access токеном проблема, он вообще не видит в headers "Authorization"